# Mapping two interfaced properties from a flat object

Tags: automapper

I have a flat object which contains multiple properties that i would like to map to different objects of a nested object. To make things even more interesting, my nested objects are interfaced and some of them share the same interface.

Before someone gets into the "Interfaces are for behavior" and that i should not have properties in em, i have to specify that this is an older codebase i have to work with and can't make dramatic changes to it.

I've searched SO for ways to provide two mapping for a single type but the solutions i have found don't deal with using them both in the same context.

Here's a simplified example of what i'm trying to map:

```
using AutoMapper;
using System;

namespace AutoMapInterfaces
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConfigureMappings();

            var source = new NestedProducts
            {
                Product1 = new ProductA { Enabled = true, Name = "1" },
                Product2 = new ProductA { Enabled = false, Name = "2" },
            };

            var products = Mapper.Map<FlatProducts>(source);
            Console.WriteLine("Product1 ({0}) State : {1}", products.Product1Name, products.Product1Enabled);
            Console.WriteLine("Product2 ({0}) State : {1}", products.Product2Name, products.Product2Enabled);

            var destination = Mapper.Map<NestedProducts>(products);
            Console.WriteLine("Product1 ({0}) State : {1}", destination.Product1.Name, destination.Product1.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Product2 ({0}) State : {1}", destination.Product2.Name, destination.Product2.Name);
        }

        private static void ConfigureMappings()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<NestedProducts, FlatProducts>();
                cfg.CreateMap<FlatProducts, NestedProducts>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Product1, 
                               opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src))
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.Product2,
                               opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));
                // Maybe ?
                //cfg.CreateMap<FlatProducts, IProduct>().ConvertUsing<FlatToNestedProductsConverter>();
            });

        }
    }


    public interface IProduct
    {
        bool Enabled { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class ProductA : IProduct
    {
        public bool Enabled { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class NestedProducts
    {
        public IProduct Product1 { get; set; }
        public IProduct Product2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class FlatProducts
    {
        public bool Product1Enabled { get; set; }
        public string Product1Name { get; set; }
        public bool Product2Enabled { get; set; }
        public string Product2Name { get; set; }
    }

}
```

I have no idea of how to go about that next, i tried a ValueResolver and a TypeConverter, but failed in both instance to differentiate between Product1 and Product2.

Comment: please post your `FlatProducts` & `NestedProducts` models

Comment: @AlexandruMarculescu Scroll down, they should be there, at least i see them